# Найти индекс первого повторяющегося элемента

Tags: python, list, numpy

Как найти первый повторяющийся подряд элемент в списке/np.array?

Например:

```
[0.5, 7, 2, 1, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Нужный индекс = 5.

Comment: Сравнивать каждый элемент со следующим. Бинго.

Comment: @Эникейщик специальной numpy/python функции нет, чтобы явно циклы не писать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение в стиле Numpy:

```
In [61]: a = np.array([0.5, 7, 2, 1, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3])

In [62]: res = np.argmax(np.diff(a) == 0)

In [63]: res
Out[63]: 5
```

---

Пошагово:

```
In [68]: np.diff(a)
Out[68]: array([ 6.5, -5. , -1. ,  8. , -6. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ])

In [69]: np.diff(a) == 0
Out[69]: array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True])

In [70]: np.argmax(np.diff(a) == 0)
Out[70]: 5
```

Comment: в условии явно не сказано, что повторяющиеся числа могут идти подряд :)

Comment: @strawdog, а как вы понимаете `"повторяющийся подряд"`? ;)

Comment: да, про "подряд" что-то у меня из головы вылетело.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [0.5, 7, 2, 1, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3]
a = next(iter([lst.index(x) for x in lst if lst.count(x) >1]))
print(a)
#5
```

Comment: Можно упростить до `next((i for i in range(len(l) - 1) if l[i] == l[i + 1]), -1)`. `-1`, что бы не получить `StopIteration`.